# How to check if two pairs of numbers are equal in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I would like to know how I can compare two pairs of numbers. I have two arrays with each element in the array in a pair format. 
For example, I have the array in this format:

```
   [(37.4,122.7), (38.4,133.2)....]
```

for each array. Now, how can compare each element of these two arrays are equal? I have tried the regular ways of checking if they are equal:

```
   a[i] == b[i]

   a[i] === b[i]
```

They do not seem to work. Could anyone please suggest a way to do this?
I am loading a JSON array of this format in to the variable 'jarr' and parsing it to jString:

```
   [{"ip":"150.101.33.44","latitude":-27.0,"longitude":133.0},
   {"ip":"150.101.33.24","latitude":-27.0,"longitude":133.0},
   {"ip":"150.101.33.7","latitude":-27.0,"longitude":133.0},
   {"ip":"150.101.33.22","latitude":-27.0,"longitude":133.0},
   {"ip":"72.14.221.174","latitude":37.4192,"longitude":-122.0574}]
```

Please find the code below:

```
   var temp = 0;
   var lat_lng = new Array(100);
   var ipArr = new Array(100);
   var jarr = '<%=request.getAttribute("locArr") %>';//This is JSON array. 
   var jString = JSON.parse(jarr);

   for(key in jString){

    var lat = JSON.stringify(jString[key].latitude);
    var lon = JSON.stringify(jString[key].longitude);
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    flag=0;

    for(var i=0;i<=temp;i++){
        if(key==0)
            {
            src="Source";
            }
        else
            {
            if(key==jString.length-1)
                {
                dest="Destination";
                }
            else
                {
                src="";
                dest="";
                }
            }
        if(key==0)
            {
            lat_lng[temp] = myLatlng;
            var a=lat_lng[i];
            ipArr[temp] = src+dest+ JSON.stringify(jString[key].ip);
            temp++;
            i++;

            }
            if(lat_lng[i] === myLatlng){ //This is where I am trying to compare
                flag=1;
                alert(flag);
                ipArr[i] +=  src+dest+JSON.stringify(jString[key].ip);
                i++;
            }


    }


    if(flag == 0)
    {
        lat_lng[temp] = myLatlng;
        ipArr[temp] = src+dest+ JSON.stringify(jString[key].ip);
        temp++;

    }


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `"They do not seem to work."` - Elaborate.

Comment: Javascript has no operator `and`. You have to use `&&` operator instead

Comment: I have an if loop which goes like this: if(lat_lng[i] === myLatlng) and the code is skipping it while executing

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear way I put it but the 'and' in the question means that I have tried both the ways of comparison. I have updated the question. Please check it now.

Comment: Post your complete code and your data-structure. As of now, all answers will be based on guess.

Comment: Code posted. Please check it now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the values you are comparing are not what you think they are. Have you tried `console.log( lat_lng[i] )` and `console.log( myLatlng )`?

Comment: You didn't post your full code (missing definitions of jString and temp)...

Comment: Please find the updated code in the question with definitions of jString, temp.

Comment: @Juhana: Thank you. I have printed them in the console and found that lat_lng[i] and myLatlng are in the same format (-27, 133) :(

Comment: I just converted the number pairs into string and it worked.  Please check my answer for details. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

Supposing `a` and `b` are arrays, you can do the following:

```
a.join() == b.join()
```

`.join()` will convert the array to a string which is then compared

Comment: But I want to compare each element of the array separately. I don't want to compare the whole arrays. Could you please tell me how I can do  that?

Comment: I have been trying the same but that's not working :(

Comment: I just converted the number pairs into string and it worked. Please check my answer for details. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var array1 = [[33.22, 22, 40], [41.33, 33, 41]];
var array2 = [[32.22, 22, 40], [42.33, 33, 41]];

for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < array1[i].length; j++){
        if(array1[i][j] == array2[i][j]){
            alert(array1[i][j] + " and " + array2[i][j] + " are equal." );
        }

        else{
            alert(array1[i][j] + " and " + array2[i][j] + " are not equal." );
        }
    }
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/sec54/)

Comment: Please find the format of arrays I have. I have updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: I just converted the number pairs into string and it worked. Please check my answer for details. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have casted it to String like below and it helped me compare the pairs:

```
   if(String(a[i]) == String(b[i]))
```